# Custom domain SSL on elastic beanstalk

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-acm

Our Multi tenant SaaS application is hosted on elastic beanstalk(EBS). EBS load balancer uses a certificate issued by ACM(Amazon certificate manager) for SSL.

We've customers who want to use their own custom domains for using our app. Is there a completely automatic way to do this(except customer setting a CNAME mapping in their DNS to our server)?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/sdk.html

Comment: @ceejayoz ACM has a quote of 10 domain names per certificate. The docs also don't mention how to use multiple certificates with EBS